# How to use static resources in spring mvc?

Tags: java, xml, spring, staticresource

How to use static resources in spring mvc? I just want to insert some images in jsp. In which place I must locate my resources? Last time I used to add mvc:recources in servlet-context, but it shows me few errors with mapping.

I'm still in trouble. I've made another question. Please, HALP.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020129/troubles-with-static-resources-and-mvcresources

My config:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">



    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.babobka.blog" />


    <import resource="../../db/db-config.xml" />



    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<strong><h1>
        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}">Blog</a>
    </h1></strong>
<p>
    <small>With Spring MVC</small><img src='<c:url value="/static/img/logo.gif"/>' />
```

And part of controller:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import net.babobka.blog.domain.Content;
import net.babobka.blog.service.ContentService;
import net.babobka.blog.domain.News;
import net.babobka.blog.service.NewsService;
import net.babobka.blog.domain.Tags;
import net.babobka.blog.service.TagsService;
import java.util.Map;
import net.babobka.blog.form.SearchForm;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private ContentService contentService;
    @Autowired
    private NewsService newsService;
    @Autowired
    private TagsService tagsService;

    long HM = 3;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listContacts(Map<String, Object> map,@ModelAttribute("search") SearchForm query, BindingResult result) {
        long nums = newsService.getNumRows();
        map.put("old", HM);
        map.put("news", new News());
        map.put("nums", nums);
        map.put("newsList", newsService.getSomeNews(0, HM));

        return "content";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/about", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAboutPage(Map<String, Object> map,@ModelAttribute("search") SearchForm query, BindingResult result) {

        map.put("news", new News());
        map.put("newsList", newsService.getAboutPage());

        return "about";
    }
```

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
        and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>

        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring/application-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>



    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>



    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>




</web-app>
```

Comment: Here is  already have answer.Check it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751597/springmvc-and-static-resources

Comment: Ok. But I'm steel having 404 after adding `<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />
 <mvc:default-servlet-handler />` in servlet-context

Comment: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/blog/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'. As I said.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting 404 error means requested resource is not applicable it means you have mapping error,After this mapping there need to check also controller-servlet.xml mapping also. If you will get error provide your code.

Try this

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

Controller-servlet.xml
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.Handler.SimpleHandlerMapping">
<property name="mapping">
<props><prop key="app.do">hello</prop></props></property></bean>
```

Comment: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/app-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/app-servlet.xml]

Comment: check properly that you have provided your view file under webcontent not inside web-inf folder.Check properly.I am also providing the anoyther mapping file in same answer.

Comment: if you  still getting 404 error means you providing your recourse file under web-inf folder that is incorrect way.

Comment: [@Rohit Jai](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1679863/rohit-jain) Please check here is some problem.

Comment: My image is in webapp/static/img/logo.gif

Answer (score 0):

Envious is right , that link contain an example you can see that. By the way , you can modify your code from the below snippet of code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ashish.stack.ques.controller"
        annotation-config="true"
        scope-resolver="org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationScopeMetadataResolver">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation"
            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>



    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

tiles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="base.definition"
        template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/menu.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="show" extends="base.definition">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Show Image" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/show.jsp" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

show.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
  Image:
  <img src='<c:url value="/static/image/radar-icon.png"/>' />
</body>
</html>
```

controller

```
    package com.ashish.stack.ques.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/show.do",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void index(){
        System.out.println("Got an image");
    }
}
```

I have modified my code , please follow the code and let me know , you get your solution or not  :)

Comment: No, I don't. I'm still having 404

Comment: My image is in webapp/static/img/logo.gif

Comment: Will you please provide us code of your controller class , jsp{where you are trying to show image} , and spring-config file. That will help us to resolve your issue.

Comment: Ok. It's in topic question

Comment: Hi I made my application based on your requirement , it's working fine in my side .. I am posting my code , just follow that I hope you will get your issue solution.

Comment: PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/blog/static/img/logo.gif] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'.

Comment: I think you done mistake in your web.xml file in url-mapping for dispatcher servlet , please show me your web.xml code

Comment: modify the url-mapping of your "DispatherServlet" from "/" to "*.do"

Comment: and also add suffix .do in your requestmapping of each method in your controller