# Include jquery in spring mvc app

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc

I am trying to include jquery in a spring mvc app but am having some trouble (I am new to spring mvc).  I created a folder called js under the webapp folder, but am not sure what to include my view to include the file.

I've tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

however, this creates a path that cannot be resolved since I have no controller for /js path.

My question is how is this usually done, is a controller created that returns the jquery-2.0.3.min.js file?

Comment: " no controller for /js path" why?

Comment: I just haven't created one, but I guess that is a solution.

Comment: You have to. That is how every project works, unless you go with those central repositroies (like Mike answered)

Comment: Do you have JS in project? No Controller (or) control? If you do have JS in project, then  web.xml entries should be enough, you don't need Controller.

Comment: @Nambari, not sure I follow...sorry I am a bit new.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-jquery-autocomplete-example/

Comment: The solution was a combination of using the link @Nambari provided above and the syntax for the view provided by EdgeCase.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this line in my JSPs, and it works.  We do not use a CDN - it is hosted locally in the javascript folder.  That folder hangs under the webapps parent.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<script src='<c:url value="/javascript/jquery.js"/>'></script>
```

Comment: I tried adding when I look at the source of the file, I just see <script src='<c:url value="/js/jquery.js"/>'></script> which does not seem to work.

Comment: additionally, I get this warning: WARRNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/<c:url value="/js/jquery.js"/>] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

Answer (score 1):

Although you could link to a CDN for common libraries such as jquery or bootstrap, most applications eventually will need some custom CSS, JS, or images.  Instead of writing a controller, you should be serving the resources via Spring MVC's ResourceServlet.  You can add the following to your webmvc-config.xml (or default-servlet.xml or whatever spring mvc configuration file you have):

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources -->
<mvc:resources location="/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

Then, you could update your view to include "resources" in the path, such as:

```
<spring:url value="/resources/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" var="jquery_js_url" />
<script src="${jquery_js_url}" type="text/javascript"><!-- /required for FF3 and Opera --></script>
```

For more information, see the following:

- http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources
- [SpringMVC and static resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751597/springmvc-and-static-resources)

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just linking to a CDN (such as Google) -- as it enables jquery to be loaded from a user's cache, rather than your servers:

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Comment: What is the difference between getting loaded from OP server and Google server?

Comment: @Nambari -- the difference is that if a user has loaded it previously (from another website), it will be in their cache -- meaning it will load instantly, rather than waiting to download then run.

Comment: @mrkb80 -- In that case, why not just hardcode it to your js folder? Including a script like this is not part of Spring. Also, Spring might already require/load in jQuery (I'm not sure, haven't used that particular framework).

Comment: I see, make sense. But few organizations/projects restrict.

Comment: I would like to avoid hardcoding as well.